# Problema DBSQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Boa tarde,
Estou com problema de sintaxe no meu código referente ao SQLite no Android Studio. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

package studio.com.projetofinal;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBcadastro {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bancodedados.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "cadastro";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private SQLiteStatement InsertStnt;
    private static final String Insert = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (nome, cpf, idade, telefone, email) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


    public DBcadastro(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        Opencadastro opencadastro = new Opencadastro(this.context);
        this.db = opencadastro.getWritableDatabase();
        this.InsertStnt = this.db.compileStatement(Insert);
    }

    public long insert (String nome, int cpf,int idade, int telefone, String email ){
        this.InsertStnt.bindString(1,nome);
        this.InsertStnt.bindLong(2,cpf);
        this.InsertStnt.bindLong(3,idade);
        this.InsertStnt.bindLong(4,telefone);
        this.InsertStnt.bindString(5,email);
        return this.InsertStnt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll (){
        this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null, null);
    }

    public List<cadastro> queryGetALL(){
        List<cadastro> list = new ArrayList<cadastro>();

        try {

            Cursor cursor = this.db.query (TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"nome", "cpf","idade", "telefone", "email"},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            int registros = cursor.getCount();

            if (registros != 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    cadastro cadastro = new cadastro(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3),cursor.getString(4));
                    list.add(cadastro);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                if (cursor  != null && ! cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close();
                    return list;
            }else
                return null;

        }

        catch (Exception err) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class Opencadastro extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        Opencadastro(Context context){
            super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IP NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome TEXT " +
                    "cpf INT, idade INT, telefone INT, email TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

        public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ana, é melhor você editar sua pergunta adicionando a exception como texto, em vez de colar imagens. Se o link das suas imagens expirar algum dia, sua pergunta ficará incompleta para futuros usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem um erro de sintaxe na SQL que cria a tabela.

A sintaxe correcta é **IF NOT EXISTS** e não **NOT EXISTS**

Em vez de `CREATE TABLE IP NOT EXISTS` use `CREATE TABLE IP IF NOT EXISTS`